# Can I use a try catch statement to catch any error instead of being specific?

Tags: c++, c, windows, exception

```
 try{
      //some function
    }catch(...){
      //write information to a file including this line number
    }
```

--

What's stopping me from doing this instead of specifying a null pointer exception for instance? The program is going to crash anyways so I might as well catch all errors if there is something I haven't thought about?

Comment: why c and windows tags?

Comment: C++ does not have null pointer exceptions.

Comment: Before asking what's stopping you, perhaps you should try it to see if it even works first.

Comment: I though the point of catching exceptions was to try and make the program not crash?

Comment: @super: Nope, `catch` simply catches any `throw`s.

Comment: C doesn't support exceptions.   In C++, there are numerous error conditions that never result in an exception being thrown.

Comment: The thing about null pointer access - is that it's "Undefined behaviour" - meaning that the compiler can do whatever it wants.  Windows VS debug binaries throw as per Paul's answer.  I wouldn't want to rely on this for release builds; and other compilers for windows will do something very different.

Answer (score 4):

It's a myth that *every* program fault will be caught by `catch(...)`. In particular the behaviour of a null pointer dereference is *undefined* so there's no guarantee at all that it would be caught there.

If you want a particularly generic `catch` site, then catching `std::exception&` is a good idea, as is `const char*`.

C++11 gives you the ability to inspect the exception in `catch(...)` to a degree via `std::current_exception`. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception.

Comment: You might as well say "will most likely not be caught there"

Comment: @lars: I know what you're saying but I tend to avoid making probability-weighted comments without being able to cite any research justifying them. And I'd be in danger of analysing undefined behaviour, and that never ends well.

Comment: @lars IIRC `catch(...)` does catch access violations (segfaults) on Windows, but I haven't tried it recently.

Answer (score 4):

In Microsoft C, an extension exists that allows you to try and catch exceptions:

```
void exceptionTest(void)
{
    int *zz = NULL;
    __try {
        *zz += 1;
    }
    __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) {
        printf("gotcha! 0x%08x\n", GetExceptionCode() );
    }
}
```

From the documentation (MSC2008):

> The try-except statement is a Microsoft extension to the C language that enables applications to gain control of a program when events that normally terminate execution occur. Such events are called exceptions, and the mechanism that deals with exceptions is called structured exception handling.
>
> Exceptions can be either hardware- or software-based. Even when applications cannot completely recover from hardware or software exceptions, structured exception handling makes it possible to display error information and trap the internal state of the application to help diagnose the problem. This is especially useful for intermittent problems that cannot be reproduced easily.

Comment: interesting, but does it answer the question?

Comment: I thought that Bill Gates et al. had enhanced this to __try, __catch nowadays? Actually I like this answer as it adds another perspective. Have an upvote!

Comment: For those that care, this "extension" is obviously platform dependent, and has a name: *structured exception handling* (it's mentioned in the citation posted in this answer). There are techniques for translating structured exceptions to language exceptions (i.e something `throw`n). Doing so is not trivial, but is nonetheless doable for the foolishly brave =).

Answer (score 0):

Being specific in exception handling facilitates the bug or probleme analysis by a human or programmatically. 
You can build an excpetion handling strategy and eventually recover from an exception. Exception is not necessarily a design flaw resulting in some unexpected null pointer. You may throw exception based on data values or process results to stop the processing or take a decision.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing things. If you dereference a null pointer then there is no automatically created exception. Dereferencing a null pointer is undefined behaviour. Once it happened its too late for exceptions. They simply wont help a bit.

On the other hand if some code checks for null pointer and then throws an exception, then this only makes sense **before** the null pointer is dereferenced, ie before undefined behaviour can occur. The program will **not** "crash anyways" when an exception is thrown in such a case (given that someone catches the exception).

Having said this, nobody will stop you from catching all excpetions. It is just that prior to C++11 you had no way to tell what exception was thrown inside a `catch(...)` block. C++11 has [`std::current_exception`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception), though I dont know much about it, so I refer you to documentation.